# C#. Передать дату в формате YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS в DateTime, не в string

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimepicker

Не получается передать дату в формате YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS в DateTime, не в string. Пробовала DateTime перевести в .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") и сконвертировать обратно в DateTime - не помогает, всё равно уходит в формате {04.10.2019 9:00:00}.

Comment: Вот на enSO хороший ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257483/c-sharp-how-to-convert-any-date-format-to-yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: У DateTime нет формата. Формат - это то, как оно представлено в виде строки. То есть вот эта фраза `передать дату в формате YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS в DateTime, не в string` смысла не имеет.

Comment: @tym32167, это не я придумала. Я обращаюсь к сервису через ServiceReference, в методе этого сервиса указано, что должно быть DateTime.

Comment: сервис какой? SOAP? WCF? Клиента сами писали или сгенерировли?

Comment: @tym32167, дали ссылку wsdl, я её добавила в ServiceReference. Остальное сама пишу. Про сервис написано, что он работает на основе обмена сообщениями и соответствует стандартам SOAP/WSDL.

Comment: Мне кажется, что формат, что используется по умолчанию, завасит о текущей культуры. Вот [похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7065972/312041)

Comment: а зачем из строки вы возвращаете обратно в дату?

Comment: @Monomax, мне показалось, что при конвертации из string  в DateTime формат сохранится, но я ошиблась.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я зашла в код ServiceReference, нашла класс метода, изменила везде тип DateTime на string. Помогло!